# Generate keys/addresses for all altcoins

Tags: altcoin, address-generation

I'm looking for a library or method to generate addresses for as many of the most popular currencies/altcoins as possible. Is there a known library that supports this? Or do I need to use a specific client for each coin?

Thanks!

Comment: You've asked multiple questions here, requiring quite big answers. I'm voting to close this as too broad until you separate the questions. Tag me a comment if you do separate them, and I'll do what I can to undo my vote or reopen it.

Comment: It's basically 1 question - whats the easiest way to generate addresses for various altcoins. @HighlyIrregular

Comment: Then perhaps the "Which altcoins use..." part of the question can be removed?

Comment: @HighlyIrregular updated

Answer (score 1):

Here is my "quite big answer":
I've successfully used http://cryptolife.net/upwg/ which is stated to be "Open Source JavaScript Client-Side Universal Paper Wallet Generator".

It doesn't generate wallet addresses by coinname, but instead by the leading character within the wallet address.  I get these from the block explorer for the coin, looking at top address.

http://www.universalwalletgenerator.net/ lets you do it by coin name.

Answer (score 1):

You should find libbitcoin's [**bx**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/Download-BX) command line interface to be quite useful. The code line references [**BIP44 Altcoin Version Mapping Table**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#bip44-altcoin-version-mapping-table) might be a bit stale, but the content of this table has strong trace-ability. [**Example 7**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#7-bitcoin-btc-bip-3944-technology-examples) through [**Example 11**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#11-ethereum-eth-bip-3944-technology-examples) should get things going quickly. These examples merely extend the initial work documented by **Andreas M. Antonopoulos** in [**Chapter 4**](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch04.asciidoc).